# How to mock FirebaseAuth verifyPhoneNumber in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, testing, firebase-authentication, flutter-bloc

I have an app that uses firebase_auth to register users using phone number. In order to write tests, I need a way to mock the firebaseAuth.verifyPhoneNumber function.

My code is as follows

```dart
class AuthBloc extends Bloc<AuthEvent, AuthState> {
  AuthBloc({
    required this.firebaseAuth,
  }) : super(const _Initial()) {
    firebaseAuth.authStateChanges().listen((event) {
      if (event != null) {
        add(AuthEvent.gotUser(event));
      }
    });
  }

  final FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

  @override
  Stream<AuthState> mapEventToState(
    AuthEvent event,
  ) async* {
 // other code here
  }

  void _verify(String phoneNo) async {
    await firebaseAuth.verifyPhoneNumber(
      phoneNumber: phoneNo,
      verificationCompleted: (PhoneAuthCredential cred) {
        add(AuthEvent.verificationCompleted(cred));
      },
      verificationFailed: (exception) {
        add(AuthEvent.verificationFailed(exception));
      },
      codeSent: (verificationId, _) {
        add(AuthEvent.codeSent(verificationId));
      },
      codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (verificationId) {
        add(AuthEvent.codeRetrievalTimeout(verificationId));
      },
      timeout: const Duration(minutes: 2),
    );
  }
}
```

```dart
  void _verify(String phoneNo) async {
    await firebaseAuth.verifyPhoneNumber(
      phoneNumber: phoneNo,
      verificationCompleted: (PhoneAuthCredential cred) {
        add(AuthEvent.verificationCompleted(cred));
      },
      verificationFailed: (exception) {
        add(AuthEvent.verificationFailed(exception));
      },
      codeSent: (verificationId, _) {
        add(AuthEvent.codeSent(verificationId));
      },
      codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (verificationId) {
        if (firebaseAuth.currentUser == null) {
          add(AuthEvent.codeRetrievalTimeout(verificationId));
        }
      },
      timeout: const Duration(minutes: 2),
      forceResendingToken: null,
    );
  }
```

In main.dart, I am using the actual firebase_auth implementation, but for testing, I am injecting MockFirebaseAuth

```dart
// main.dart
AuthBloc(
    firebaseAuth: firebaseAuth,
)
```

Then in auth_bloc_test.dart, I have

```dart
// auth_bloc_test.dart
AuthBloc(
  firebaseAuth: MockFirebaseAuth(
    signedIn: false,
    mockUser: MockUser(
      phoneNumber: '0714109322',
    ),
  ),
)
```

I have tried using [firebase_auth_mocks](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_auth_mocks) but it gives me an error saying

> NoSuchMethodError: Class 'MockFirebaseAuth' has no instance method 'verifyPhoneNumber' with matching arguments.

Is there a way I can mock the verifyPhoneNumber to trigger the functions verificationCompleted: (PhoneAuthCredential cred) {},verificationFailed: (exception) {},
codeSent: (verificationId, _) {},codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (verificationId) {}

Comment: Hello, did you find the solution for this because i struggle with the same problem.